# SQL query in BIRT Eclipse not working

Tags: sql, eclipse, where-clause, birt

I have the following code that works when I do not include the where clause.
where am I going wrong?

It runs successfully in SQL Server.

Thanks.

```
maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());
maximoDataSet.open();

var sqlText = new String();

// Add query to sqlText variable.
sqlText = " select workorder.wonum, workorder.description, workorder.status, workorder.targstartdate, workorder.targcompdate, "
+ "workorder.schedstart, workorder.schedfinish, workorder.actstart, workorder.actfinish, workorder.reportedby, workorder.lead, workorder.assetnum, workorder.location "
+ "from workorder"
// Include the Maximo where clause
+ " where workorder.targcompdate < GetDate()" 
;

maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);
```

edit*

resolved by just using 
+ " where workorder.targcompdate <  '2017-02-28'"

not sure how to use getDate() in birt

Comment: Do you get any error or it doesn't bring any records?

Comment: it doesn't bring any records, doesn't give an error

Comment: If you run the query in SQL Server with the where condition do you get any records? Also, you can use the SQL Server Profiler to see the query that is executed and confirm that it is correct